# Revtex4-1 and algorithm2e indentation clash

Tags: revtex, algorithm2e

there seems to exists a clash between revtex4-1 and the algorithm2e package. Whenever I try to insert an *algorithm* block when using the *revtex4-1* document class, the tabulation is not working properly. The following latex code should hopefully be self explanatory.

```
%\documentclass[10]{article}
\documentclass[10]{revtex4-1}

% these are to avoid another clash between revtex and algorithm2e
\makeatletter
\newif\if@restonecol
\makeatother
\let\algorithm\relax
\let\endalgorithm\relax
% needed includes
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

The following pseudocode exibits a clash between revtex4-1 and algorithm2e.

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate something}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR{every thing you}
    \FOR{every step you}
        \STATE{compute something}
    \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This is a how the rendered pdf shows on my system (sorry, I'm not allowed to insert images in this post). The tabulation is correct when using the simple *article* document class. I am using Texmaker (with texLive) under Ubuntu 10.04.

Using the *revtex4-1* document class:

```
for every thing you do
for every step you do
compute something
end for
end for
```

Using the *article* document class:

```
for every thing you do
    for every step you do
        compute something
    end for
end for
```

Anybody with a solution to make these two work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an incompatibility between the `algorithm2e`/`algorithmic` packages and `revtex4-1`; one possibility is to use `algcompatible` instead of `algorithmic` (the syntax of the commands is the same and this solves the indentation problem) and to use the `newfloat` package to define a new `algorithm` float. Here's an example illustrating this approach (I used a `table` and a `figure` environments to show how the newly defined float behaves consistently with the class):

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of Algorithms,
    name=ALGORITHM,
    placement=tbhp,
]{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption for a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption for a table}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR{every thing you}
    \FOR{every step you}
        \STATE{compute something}
    \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Calculate something}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wants to keep the `ruled` style of the `algorithm` environmet, as defined in `algorithm2e`, some additional work has to be done; in this case, the `caption` package could be used (providing one makes the necessary adjustments to recover the formatting defined in `revtex4-1`); here's such possibility with a little example:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{newfloat,algcompatible}
\usepackage[size=small]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\noindent\hrulefill\par\nobreak\vskip-5pt}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of Algorithms,
    name=ALGORITHM,
    placement=tbhp,
]{algorithm}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algorithms}{\vskip-15pt\hrulefill\par#1#2#3\vskip-6pt\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off,format=algorithms}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption for a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR{every thing you}
    \FOR{every step you}
        \STATE{compute something}
    \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Calculate something}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reason, the `newfloat` packageis not available, one can use the `trivfloat` instead:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage[floatrow]{trivfloat}

\trivfloat{algorithm}
\renewcommand\algorithmname{ALGORITHM}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption for a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption for a table}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR{every thing you}
    \FOR{every step you}
        \STATE{compute something}
    \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Calculate something}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, that fixed the indentation problem. Could you try compiling using the following document class: \documentclass{revtex4-1}. On my system, the document is rendered properly but I get the following errors when doing so:! Missing \endcsname... ! Missing number, treated as zero... ! Extra \endcsname...

Comment: @raspoutine Hmmm. You're right, Using revtex4-1 produces an error, this time due to the algorithm package. Could using another package be an option for you? (algorithm only provides the rules and the caption, but that can be produced with other packages).

Comment: @raspoutine I updated my answer with two possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, using another package is an option for me. I'm not sticked to any alg* package, I just fancy the nice vertical lines and the line numbering provided by some packages. But the revtex4-1 is not an option, as it is required by my publisher.

Comment: @raspoutine then perhaps one of the options I gave in my updated answer is useful for you? (Unfortunately, vertical lines are not easy to achieve now).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to load the *newfloat* package, so there is no way I can test your answers right now. I understand *newfloat* is a part of the *caption* package, the latter being properly installed on my system.

Comment: @raspoutine `newfloat` is a spin-off from `caption`. Perhaps your system is not updated? Can you update it? If not, I could think of another alternative.

Comment: We'll be using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for quite a while in my lab, so the upgrade solution might be difficult.

Comment: @raspoutine I see; then I'll think about another approach and let you know (perhaps not today, since I'm a little tired, but in some hours).

Comment: @raspoutine I updated my answer with another option, this time using the `trivfloat` package. Please let me know if this is a valid option for you.

Comment: The solution using *trivfloat* worked for me. It won't let me use the fancy *ruled* or *vlined* options provided by *algorithm2e*, but at least it compiles without error on my 2-year outdated system. Thank you very much @Gonzalo.

Comment: Before closing this post, I realized that the solution using the *trivfloat* affected the rest of my original document. The captions from Tables now appear below (they need to appear above the Tables). It also seems to affect the *\textwidth* property in a 2-column environment.

Comment: @raspoutine hmmm... that's not good. I'll have to think about other possibility; unfortunately until Monday I will be really busy so I don't think I can provide another approach (I have an idea but have to test it first) until Monday. I hope you're not on a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

I had to work out a bit the solution provided by Gonzalo Medina using Revtex4-1 to fix some horizontal line placement when floating the pseudocode and putting the caption at the top of it and also update the very usefull \Comment command (also add an \Input command that might be usefull for some of you).

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,reprint,groupedaddress,amsmath, amssymb, showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{newfloat,algcompatible}
\usepackage[size=small]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtEndEnvironment{algorithm}{\noindent\hrulefill\par\nobreak\vskip-8pt}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of Algorithms,
    name=ALGORITHM,
    placement=tbhp,
]{algorithm}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algorithms}{\vskip-15pt\hrulefill\par#1#2#3\vskip-6pt\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off,format=algorithms}

%\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill\(\triangleright\) #1}%       

\algblock[Input]{Input}{EndInput}
\algblockdefx[Input]{Input}{EndInput}%
    [1]{\textbf{Input} #1}%
    {}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption {Compute Something}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Input{Something you have}\EndInput
\FOR{Something you know}
\State{Something you can}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you don't have the newfloat package available in your miktex distributino, you should be able to found it here

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption

just download the entire caption package, compile caption.ins using latex and this will create newfloat.sty that you can move to your local directory.

Best