# algorithm2e with RevTex

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, revtex

*Note: I have seen the previous answer to this problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70181/revtex4-1-and-algorithm2e-indentation-clash) and it doesn't work for my purposes.  I suspect that others are in the same boat.*

I'm writing a paper for which the publisher requires the use of RevTex 4.1.  I have several pages worth of algorithms already written using the `algorithm2e` package.  But when I went to put them in the paper, all of the indentation failed.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[aip,jcp]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \ForEach{i}{
    \ForEach{j}{
      hello world\;
    }
  }
  \caption{This is wrong: no indentation}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which gives:
[image: Output]

Am I stuck rewriting pages and pages of algorithms in `algorithmic` syntax (or something else), or is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: There are two answers in the link you provided? None of them works?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Both answers use the `algcompatible` package, which uses `algorithmic` syntax (as opposed to `algorithm2e` syntax).  I would have to rewrite all of my algorithms in a different syntax.  Not impossible, but a lot of work that I'd rather not do if a workaround exists.

Comment: Yes, I see... no, this is should be only the last method to be applied.

Comment: @DavidHollman Any solutions yet? I have the same problem

Comment: @smörkex, this is still a known bug of `algorithm2e`

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create a pdf of the algorithm, using the preview package, after which you include that pdf in your document using `\includegraphics`. Note you would have to use the same font, text width, etc., to prevent discrepancies between the markup of your algorithm block and the rest of your document.

The following code example creates the pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
  
\begin{algorithm}[H]
% Your algo here 
\end{algorithm}

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

**Added:**

To incorporate the algorithm in your main tex file as a float, you could use the figure environment. However, in that case, the caption would say "Figure X: ..." instead "Algorithm X: ... ". Additionally, you'd want to use a different counter for your algorithms and figures. To accomplish this, use the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    name=Algorithm
]{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\Roman{algorithm}}

\begin{algorithm}
  \hrule
  \includegraphics{algo.pdf}
  \hrule
  \caption{\label{alg:myalg} caption}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```