# Algorithm in RevTex4-1

Tags: algorithms, revtex

When I run the attached code I get this error:

```
************************************
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@float@type 
l.23 \end{algorithm}
************************************
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}
  \caption{Hello}
  \label{EPSA}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $T_m= \min\limits_k (T_c(k)),  k_m= \arg\min\limits_k (T_c(k))$
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70181/27635

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem was that the commands were not capitalized, i.e., instead of \State, I should have written \STATE. However, the caption is still at the bottom of the algorithm. Any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Floating environments created with the `float` package (as `algorithm` is) are incompatible with the `revtex4-1` class.

The only way you have to include such an environment in your document, is to use the floating specifier `H`, which avoids the environment to float.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{float} % loaded by algorithm
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Hello}
  \label{EPSA}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $T_m= \min\limits_k (T_c(k)),  k_m= \arg\min\limits_k (T_c(k))$
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to let it float, you can insert the `algorithm` inside a `figure` environment without caption. In this way the algorithm caption also respects the `revtex4-1` directives.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{float} % loaded by algorithm
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Hello}
  \label{EPSA}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $T_m= \min\limits_k (T_c(k)),  k_m= \arg\min\limits_k (T_c(k))$
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, if you want it to span two columns, you can insert it inside a `figure*` environment. If you also want the lines to span the two columns, insert it first in a `minipage` of `\linewidth` width.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{float} % loaded by algorithm
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Hello}
  \label{EPSA}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $T_m= \min\limits_k (T_c(k)),  k_m= \arg\min\limits_k (T_c(k))$
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @karlkoeller. Your explanations solved my problem.