# Algorithmic error: Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: algorithmic

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,aps,pre,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,floatfix,longbibliography,superscriptaddress,notitlepage]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\text{\normalfont\AA}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}
\title{Lipsum}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Lipsum Generator}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{lipsum}
\label{proc:lipsum}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{MapGen}{}
\State lorem
\State ipsum
\State dolor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

I am getting the following error messages during compilation:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted \end{algorithm}
Missing number, treated as zero \end{algorithm}
Extra \endcsname \end{algorithm}
```

The weirdest part is, it compiles and produces a correct .pdf file. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please, add a complete compilable example. My attempt, loading `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` works without any error.

Comment: @egreg I modified my question.

Comment: @egreg I think the problem is revtex. When I change the document class to article, it does not give an error.

Comment: @egreg Ok, figured it out. Apparently there is a problem with the float: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231191/algorithm-in-revtex4-1

Comment: So we can close this as duplicate, I guess.