# ! Missing \endcsname inserted in \end {algorithmic}

Tags: texmaker, algorithms, algpseudocode

I have the following code:

```
    \documentclass{AIAA}

        \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{my algorithm}\label{myalg}
          \begin{algorithmic}[1]
          \State Inputs: $N_s$, $\Delta t$, $\lambda_{min}$, $M$, $M_{max}, \phi_i\   i \in [1,N_s]$
          \State $N_g \gets {\rm ceil}(N_s/M)$ \Comment{Set initial number of groups}
           \State $\lambda_i \gets \Delta t \ i \in [1,N_s]$ \Comment{Set initial weightings}

          \Loop 
          \State $N_s' = 0$ \Comment{Counter of modes for next level}
        \State  \Comment{Loop over each group}
          \For{$i\gets 1, N_g$}
         \State $\vec{I}\gets (i-1)M+1:$ $\min(i M,N_s)$  \Comment{Indices for snapshots in group}
         \State $C \gets (\phi_{\vec{I}},\phi_{\vec{I}}^T)$ \Comment{Snapshot matrix inner product}%
         \State $D \gets {\rm diag}(\lambda_{\vec{I}}$) \Comment{Create weighting matrix}
         \State Solve $ D C \vec{\psi} = \vec{\psi} \lambda'$  \Comment{Eigenvalues from largest to smallest}
         \State $N' \gets \max(\left\{\ i\ |\ \lambda'_i > \lambda_{min}\right\})$ \Comment{Number of eigenvalues to keep}
         \State $\vec{I}' \gets N_s'+1:N_s'+N'$ \Comment{New indices}
         \State $\phi_{\vec{I}'} \gets \psi_{1:N'}^T \phi_{\vec{I}}$ \Comment{Replaces snapshots}
         \State $\lambda_{\vec{I}'} \gets \lambda'_{1:N'}$  \Comment{Replaces eigenvalues}
         \State $N_s' \gets N_s' +N'$ \Comment{Increase counter}
        \EndFor
     \EndLoop
        \Return $N_s$, $\phi_{1:N_s}$, $\lambda_{1:N_s}$, $\lambda_{min}$
           \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and I receive the following errors:

[image]

The style of the documents is also enclosed to the question. If one uses these two files, the errors would come up. Any idea about the reason of errors and how to fix it?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{AIAA}%
\LoadClass[manuscript]{revtex4-1}[2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)]
\def\class@name{revtex4-1}%
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,oneside,onecolumn,final}%
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{latexsym}%
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}%
\RequirePackage{verbatim}%
\RequirePackage[leqno]{amsmath}[2.14]
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{12}%
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \abovedisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip
   \belowdisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI
}%
\def\small{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{10.5}%
  \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
  \def\@listi{%
    \leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
    \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \itemsep \parsep
  }%
}%
\def\footnotesize{%
  \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5pt}%
  \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
  \def\@listi{%
    \leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \itemsep \parsep
  }%
}%
\def\scriptsize{%
 \@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt
}%
\def\tiny{%
 \@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt
}%
\def\large{%
 \@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14pt}%
}%
\def\Large{%
 \@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18pt}%
}%
\def\LARGE{%
 \@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22pt}%
}%
\def\huge{%
 \@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25pt}%
}%
\def\Huge{%
 \@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30pt}%
}%
 \@ifxundefined\twoside@sw{\@booleanfalse\twoside@sw}{}%
 \twoside@sw{%
    \oddsidemargin  -20pt
    \evensidemargin -20pt
    \marginparwidth 107pt
 }{%
    \oddsidemargin  .15in
    \evensidemargin .15in
    \marginparwidth 30pt
 }%
\marginparsep 6pt
\topmargin -61pt
\headheight 25pt
\headsep 16pt
\topskip 10pt
\footskip 30pt
 \textheight = 56pc
\textwidth36pc
\columnsep 1.5pc
\columnseprule 0pt
\footnotesep 1pt
\skip\footins 39pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\def\footnoterule{\kern-19pt\hrule width.5in\kern18.6pt\relax}%
\floatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\textfloatsep 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\intextsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\dblfloatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\dbltextfloatsep 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\@fptop 0pt plus 1fil
\@fpsep 8pt plus 2fil
\@fpbot 0pt plus 1fil
\@dblfptop 0pt plus 1fil
\@dblfpsep 8pt plus 2fil
\@dblfpbot 0pt plus 1fil
\marginparpush 5pt
\parskip 0pt plus 1pt
\parindent 1.5pc
\emergencystretch8\p@
\partopsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\leftmargini 25pt
\leftmarginii 22pt
\leftmarginiii 18.7pt
\leftmarginiv 17pt
\leftmarginv 10pt
\leftmarginvi 10pt
\def\@listI{%
  \leftmargin\leftmargini
  \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@
  \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@
  \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@
}%
\labelsep 4pt
\def\@listii{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginii
  \labelwidth\leftmarginii
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
  \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@
  \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@
  \itemsep \parsep
}%
\def\@listiii{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginiii
  \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
  \topsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@
  \parsep \z@
  \partopsep \p@ plus\z@ minus\p@
  \itemsep \topsep
}%
\def\@listiv{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginiv
  \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
}%
\def\@listv{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginv
  \labelwidth\leftmarginv
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
}%
\def\@listvi{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginvi
  \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% from class file



\def\affils@present@group#1{%
 \begingroup
   \def\AF@temp{#1}%
   \@tempcnta\z@
   \let\AU@opr \@undefined
   \let\CO@opr \@undefined
   \def\AF@opr{\@affilID@count\AF@temp\@tempcnta}%
   \@AAC@list
   \@ifnum{\@tempcnta=\z@}{}{%
    \begingroup
     \frontmatter@above@affilgroup
     \set@listcomma@count\@tempcnta
     \let\AU@opr \@undefined
     \let\CO@opr \@undefined
     \def\AF@opr{\@affilID@match\AF@temp}%
     \@AAC@list
    \endgroup
    \begingroup
     \par
          \vskip-.5\baselineskip
     \frontmatter@above@affiliation
     \frontmatter@affiliationfont
     \let\\\frontmatter@addressnewline
     \@tempcnta\z@
     \@tfor\AF@temp:=#1\do{%
      \expandafter\@ifx\expandafter{\expandafter\z@\AF@temp}{}{%
       \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
      }%
     }%
     \@ifnum{\@tempcnta=\tw@}{%
      \let\@listcomma\relax
     }{}%
     \def@after@address
     \runinaddress@sw{%
     }{%
      \tightenlines@sw{
      }{%
       \parskip\z@
      }%
      \appdef\after@address\par
     }%
     \let\AFF@opr \@affil@group
     \do@affil@fromgroup\@AFF@list#1\relax
    \endgroup
   }%
   \par
 \endgroup
}%

\def\def@after@address{\def\after@address{\@listcomma\ \@listand}}%
\def\def@after@address@empty{\let\after@address\@empty}%


\def\frontmatter@thefootnote{%
 \altaffilletter@sw{\@alph}{\@fnsymbol}{\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname}%
}%

\let\ltx@footnote@pop\@empty

\def\titleblock@produce{%
 \begingroup
  \ltx@footnote@pop
  \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}%
  \def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}%
  \c@mpfootnote\z@
  \let\@makefnmark\frontmatter@makefnmark
  \frontmatter@setup
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}\label{FirstPage}%
  \frontmatter@title@produce
  \groupauthors@sw{%
   \frontmatter@author@produce@group
  }{%
   \frontmatter@author@produce@script
  }%
  \frontmatter@RRAPformat{%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@date}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@received}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@revised}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@accepted}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@published}%
  }%
  \frontmatter@abstract@produce
  \@ifx@empty\@pacs{}{%
   \@pacs@produce\@pacs
  }%
  \@ifx@empty\@keywords{}{%
   \@keywords@produce\@keywords
  }%
  \par
  \frontmatter@finalspace
 \endgroup
}%


\def\frontmatter@title@produce{%
 \begingroup
  \frontmatter@title@above
  \frontmatter@title@format\LARGE
  \@title
  \unskip
  \phantomsection\expandafter\@argswap@val\expandafter{\@title}{\addcontentsline{toc}{title}}%
  \@ifx{\@title@aux\@title@aux@cleared}{}{%
   \expandafter\frontmatter@footnote\expandafter{\@title@aux}%
  }%
  \par
  \frontmatter@title@below
 \endgroup
}%



\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \aftermaketitle@chk{\begin{abstract}}%
  \global\setbox\absbox\vbox\bgroup
   \color@begingroup
   \columnwidth\textwidth
   \hsize\columnwidth
   \@parboxrestore
   \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}\def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}\c@mpfootnote\z@
   \let\@footnotetext\frontmatter@footnotetext
   \minipagefootnote@init
   \let\@listdepth\@mplistdepth \@mplistdepth\z@
   \@minipagerestore
   \@setminipage
    %\frontmatter@abstractheading
    %\frontmatter@abstractfont%
    \vskip1pc
    \bfseries\hskip1pc
    \let\footnote\mini@note
}{%
    \par
    \unskip
    \minipagefootnote@here
    \@minipagefalse   %% added 24 May 89
    \color@endgroup
  \egroup
}%

\let\prep@absbox\@empty
\let\post@absbox\@empty

\def\frontmatter@abstract@produce{%
  \par
  \preprintsty@sw{%
   \do@output@MVL{%
    \vskip\frontmatter@preabstractspace
    \vskip200\p@%\@plus1fil
    \penalty-200\relax
    \vskip-200\p@%\@plus-1fil
   }%
  }{%
   \addvspace{\frontmatter@preabstractspace}%
  }%
   \begingroup
    \dimen@\baselineskip
    \setbox\z@\vtop{\unvcopy\absbox}%
    \advance\dimen@-\ht\z@\advance\dimen@-\prevdepth
    \@ifdim{\dimen@>\z@}{\vskip\dimen@}{}%
   \endgroup
   \begingroup
    \prep@absbox
    \unvbox\absbox
    \post@absbox
   \endgroup
  \@ifx{\@empty\mini@notes}{}{\mini@notes\par}%
  \addvspace\frontmatter@postabstractspace
}%

\def\maketitle{%
  \@author@finish
  \title@column\titleblock@produce
  \suppressfloats[t]%
  \let\and\relax
  \let\affiliation\@gobble
  \let\author\@gobble
  \let\@AAC@list\@empty
  \let\@AFF@list\@empty
  \let\@AFG@list\@empty
  \let\@AF@join\@AF@join@error
  \let\email\@gobble
  \let\@address\@empty
  \let\maketitle\relax
  \let\thanks\@gobble
  \titlepage@sw{%
  %\vfil
  %\clearpage
  \vspace*{12pt}
  }{}%
}%

\renewcommand\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
\def\tablename{Table}
\def\figurename{Fig.}

\newcommand{\od}[2] {\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\pd}[2] {\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\pdl}[2] {{\partial #1}/{\partial #2}}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \par
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
   \small\rmfamily
   \sbox\@tempboxa{%
    \let\\\heading@cr
     {\bf #1 #2}%
   }%
   \@ifdim{\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize}{%
    \begingroup
     \samepage
     \flushing
     \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
     {\bf #1 #2}\par%
    \endgroup
   }{%
     \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\unhbox\@tempboxa\hfil}%
   }%
  \endgroup
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}%

\def\@make@capt@title#1#2{%
 \@ifx@empty\float@link{\@firstofone}{\expandafter\href\expandafter{\float@link}}%
  {#1}\@caption@fignum@sep#2%
}%

\def\@caption@fignum@sep{. }%
\def\setfloatlink{\def\float@link}%
\let\float@link\@empty

%%%%%%%%%%%% From APS4-1.rtx

\ifx\undefined\substyle@ext
 \def\@tempa{%
  \endinput
  \GenericWarning{I must be read in by REVTeX! (Bailing out)}%
 }%
 \expandafter\else
  \def\@tempa{}%
 \expandafter\fi\@tempa
 \class@info{RevTeX society APS selected}%

\def\ao{Appl.\  Opt.}%
\def\ap{Appl.\  Phys.}%
\def\apl{Appl.\ Phys.\ Lett.}%
\def\apj{Astrophys.\ J.}%
\def\bell{Bell Syst.\ Tech.\ J.}%
\def\jqe{IEEE J.\ Quantum Electron.}%
\def\assp{IEEE Trans.\ Acoust.\ Speech Signal Process.}%
\def\aprop{IEEE Trans.\ Antennas Propag.}%
\def\mtt{IEEE Trans.\ Microwave Theory Tech.}%
\def\iovs{Invest.\ Ophthalmol.\ Vis.\ Sci.}%
\def\jcp{J.\ Chem.\ Phys.}%
\def\jmo{J.\ Mod.\ Opt.}%
\def\josa{J.\ Opt.\ Soc.\ Am.}%
\def\josaa{J.\ Opt.\ Soc.\ Am.\ A}%
\def\josab{J.\ Opt.\ Soc.\ Am.\ B}%
\def\jpp{J.\ Phys.\ (Paris)}%
\def\nat{Nature (London)}%
\def\oc{Opt.\ Commun.}%
\def\ol{Opt.\ Lett.}%
\def\pl{Phys.\ Lett.}%
\def\pra{Phys.\ Rev.\ A}%
\def\prb{Phys.\ Rev.\ B}%
\def\prc{Phys.\ Rev.\ C}%
\def\prd{Phys.\ Rev.\ D}%
\def\pre{Phys.\ Rev.\ E}%
\def\prl{Phys.\ Rev.\ Lett.}%
\def\rmp{Rev.\ Mod.\ Phys.}%
\def\pspie{Proc.\ Soc.\ Photo-Opt.\ Instrum.\ Eng.}%
\def\sjqe{Sov.\ J.\ Quantum Electron.}%
\def\vr{Vision Res.}%
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
 \ensuremath{%
  \ifcase#1\or
   *\or
   \dagger\or
   \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or
   \mathparagraph\or
   **\or
   \dagger\dagger\or
   \ddagger\ddagger\else
   \mathsection\mathsection\or
   \mathparagraph\mathparagraph\or
   ***\or
   \dagger\dagger\dagger\or
   \ddagger\ddagger\ddagger\else
   \mathsection\mathsection\mathsection\or
   \mathparagraph\mathparagraph\mathparagraph\or
   \@ctrerr
  \fi
 }%
}%
\appdef\document@inithook{%
 \@ifxundefined\TextOrMath{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\TextOrMath{\@ifmmode{\false@sw}{\true@sw}}%
 }{}%
}%
\let\thefootnote@latex\thefootnote
\clo@groupedaddress
\renewenvironment{titlepage}{%
  \let\wastwocol@sw\twocolumn@sw
  \onecolumngrid
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
  \c@page\z@
}{%
  \wastwocol@sw{\twocolumngrid}{\newpage}%
}%
\def\frontmatter@abstractheading{%
 \preprintsty@sw{%
  \begingroup
   \centering\large
   \abstractname
   \par
  \endgroup
 }{}%
}%
\def\frontmatter@abstractwidth{400\p@}%
\def\frontmatter@abstractfont{%
 \small
 \parindent1em\relax
 \adjust@abstractwidth
}%
\def\adjust@abstractwidth{%
 \dimen@\textwidth\advance\dimen@-\frontmatter@abstractwidth
 \divide\dimen@\tw@
 \galley@sw{%
  \advance\rightskip\tw@\dimen@
 }{%
  \advance\leftskip\dimen@
  \advance\rightskip\dimen@
 }%
 \@totalleftmargin\leftskip
}%
\@booleanfalse\preprintsty@sw
\@booleantrue\titlepage@sw
\appdef\setup@hook{%
  \preprintsty@sw{%
   \ps@preprint
   \def\frontmatter@abstractwidth{\textwidth}%
   \def\frontmatter@affiliationfont{\it}%
   \let\section\section@preprintsty
   \let\subsection\subsection@preprintsty
   \let\subsubsection\subsubsection@preprintsty
  }{%
   \ps@article
  }%
}%
\def\frontmatter@authorformat{%
 \skip@\@flushglue
 \@flushglue\z@ plus.3\hsize\relax
 \centering
 \advance\baselineskip\p@
 \parskip11.5\p@\relax
 \@flushglue\skip@
}%
\def\frontmatter@above@affilgroup{%
}%
\def\frontmatter@above@affiliation@script{%
 \skip@\@flushglue
 \@flushglue\z@ plus.3\hsize\relax
 \centering
 \@flushglue\skip@
 \addvspace{3.5\p@}%
}%
\def\frontmatter@above@affiliation{%
 \preprintsty@sw{}{%
 }%
}%
\def\frontmatter@affiliationfont{%
\it
}%
\def\frontmatter@collaboration@above{%
 \preprintsty@sw{%
 }{%
  \parskip1.5\p@\relax
 }%
}%
\def\frontmatter@setup{%
 \normalfont
}%
\def\frontmatter@title@above{\addvspace{6\p@}}%
\def\frontmatter@title@format{\large\bfseries\centering\parskip\z@skip}%
\def\frontmatter@title@below{}%
\def\@author@parskip{3\p@}%
\def\frontmatter@makefnmark{%
 \@textsuperscript{%
  \normalfont\@thefnmark
 }%
}%
\def\frontmatter@authorbelow{%
 \addvspace{3\p@}%
}%
\def\frontmatter@RRAP@format{%
  \small
  \centering
  \everypar{\hbox\bgroup(\@gobble@leavemode@uppercase}%
  \def\par{\@ifvmode{}{\unskip)\egroup\@@par}}%
}%
\def\punct@RRAP{;\egroup\ \hbox\bgroup}%
\def\@gobble@leavemode@uppercase#1#2{\expandafter\MakeTextUppercase}%
\def\frontmatter@PACS@format{%
   \addvspace{11\p@}%
   \footnotesize
   \adjust@abstractwidth
   \parindent\z@
   \parskip\z@skip
   \samepage
}%
\def\frontmatter@keys@format{%
   \footnotesize
   \adjust@abstractwidth
   \parindent\z@
   \samepage
}%
\def\ps@titlepage{%
  \def\@oddhead{%
   \hfill
   \preprint@sw{%
    \expandafter\produce@preprints\expandafter{\@preprint}%
   }{}%
  }%
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
  \def\@oddfoot{%
   \hb@xt@\z@{\byrevtex\hss}%
   \hfil
   \preprintsty@sw{\thepage}{}%
   \quad\checkindate
   \hfil
  }%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}%
\def\byrevtex{\byrevtex@sw{Typeset by REV\TeX}{}}%
\def\produce@preprints#1{%
 \vtop to \z@{%
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \small
  \let\preprint\preprint@count
  \count@\z@
  #1%
  \@ifnum{\count@>\tw@}{%
   \hbox{%
    \let\preprint\preprint@hlist
    #1%
    \setbox\z@\lastbox
   }%
  }{%
   \let\preprint\preprint@cr
   \halign{\hfil##\cr#1\crcr}%
   \par
   \vss
  }%
 }%
}%
\def\preprint@cr#1{#1\cr}%
\def\preprint@count#1{\advance\count@\@ne}%
\def\preprint@hlist#1{#1\hbox{, }}%
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}%
\def\@hang@from#1#2#3{#1#2#3}%
\def\section{%
  \@startsection
    {section}%
    {1}%
    {\z@}%
    {0.4cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {0.1cm}%
    {%
      \normalfont\small\bfseries
      \centering
    }%
}%
\def\@hangfrom@section#1#2#3{\@hangfrom{#1#2}{#3}}
\def\@hangfroms@section#1#2{#1{#2}}

\def\subsection{%
  \@startsection
    {subsection}%
    {2}%
    {\z@}%
    {0.4cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {0.1cm}%
    {%
 \noindent\normalfont\small\bfseries
    }%
}%
\def\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}%
    {3}%
    {\z@}%
    {.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {.5cm}%
    {%
     \normalfont\small\itshape
    \centering
    }%
}%
\def\paragraph{%
  \@startsection
    {paragraph}%
    {4}%
    {\parindent}%
    {\z@}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}%
}%
\def\subparagraph{%
  \@startsection
    {subparagraph}%
    {5}%
    {\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}%
\def\section@preprintsty{%
  \@startsection
    {section}%
    {1}%
    {\z@}%
    {0.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {0.0001cm}%
    {%
      \normalfont\small\bfseries\centering
    }%
}%
\def\subsection@preprintsty{%
  \@startsection
    {subsection}%
    {2}%
    {-\parindent}%
    {.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {.0001cm}%
    {%
     \normalfont\small\bfseries
    }%
}%
\def\subsubsection@preprintsty{%
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}%
    {3}%
    {\z@}%
    {.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {.0001cm}%
    {%
     \normalfont\small\itshape
    }%
}%
\let\frontmatter@footnote@produce\frontmatter@footnote@produce@footnote
\def\@pnumwidth{1.55em}%
\def\@tocrmarg {2.55em}%
\def\@dotsep{2}%
\def\ltxu@dotsep{4.5pt}%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}%
\def\tableofcontents{%
 \addtocontents{toc}{\string\tocdepth@munge}%
 \print@toc{toc}%
 \addtocontents{toc}{\string\tocdepth@restore}%
}%
\def\tocdepth@munge{%
  \let\l@section@saved\l@section
  \let\l@section\@gobble@tw@
}%
\def\@gobble@tw@#1#2{}%
\def\tocdepth@restore{%
  \let\l@section\l@section@saved
}%
\def\l@part#1#2{\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}%
 \begingroup
  \set@tocdim@pagenum\@tempboxa{#2}%
  \parindent \z@
  \rightskip\tocleft@pagenum plus 1fil\relax
  \skip@\parfillskip\parfillskip\z@
  \addvspace{2.25em plus\p@}%
  \large \bf %
  \leavevmode\ignorespaces#1\unskip\nobreak\hskip\skip@
  \hb@xt@\rightskip{\hfil\unhbox\@tempboxa}\hskip-\rightskip\hskip\z@skip
  \par
  \nobreak %
 \endgroup
}%
\def\tocleft@{\z@}%
\def\tocdim@min{5\p@}%
\def\l@section{%
 \l@@sections{}{section}% Implicit #3#4
}%
\def\l@f@section{%
 \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}%
 \addvspace{1.0em plus\p@}%
 %\bf
}%
\def\l@subsection{%
 \l@@sections{section}{subsection}% Implicit #3#4
}%
\def\l@subsubsection{%
 \l@@sections{subsection}{subsubsection}% Implicit #3#4
}%
\def\l@paragraph#1#2{}%
\def\l@subparagraph#1#2{}%
\let\toc@pre\toc@pre@auto
\let\toc@post\toc@post@auto
\@booleanfalse\raggedcolumn@sw
\def\tableft@skip@float{\z@ plus\hsize}%
\def\tabmid@skip@float{\@flushglue}%
\def\tabright@skip@float{\z@ plus\hsize}%
\def\array@row@pre@float{\hline\hline\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}}%
\def\array@row@pst@float{\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}\hline\hline}%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
 \def\baselinestretch{1}%
 \leftskip1em%
 \parindent1em%
 \noindent
 \nobreak\hskip-\leftskip
 \hb@xt@\leftskip{%
  \hss\@makefnmark\ %
 }%
 #1%
 \par
}%
\long\def\frontmatter@makefntext#1{%
 \def\baselinestretch{1}%
 \leftskip1em%
 \parindent1em%
 \noindent
 \nobreak\hskip-\leftskip
 \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{frontmatter.\expandafter\the\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname}\hyper@anchorend}%
 \hb@xt@\leftskip{%
  \hss\@makefnmark\ %
 }%
 #1%
 \par
}%
\prepdef\appendix{%
 \par
 \let\@hangfrom@section\@hangfrom@appendix
 \let\@sectioncntformat\@appendixcntformat
}%
\def\@hangfrom@appendix#1#2#3{%
 #1%
 \@if@empty{#2}{%
  #3%
 }{%
  #2\@if@empty{#3}{}{:\ #3}%
 }%
}%
\def\@hangfroms@appendix#1#2{%
 #1#2%
}%
\def\@appendixcntformat#1{\appendixname\ \csname the#1\endcsname}%
\@booleanfalse\authoryear@sw
\appdef\setup@hook{%
 \bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{,}%
}%
 \def\pre@bibdata{\jobname\bibdata@app}%
\appdef\setup@hook{%
 \def\bibsection{%
  \par
  \onecolumngrid@push
  \begingroup
   \baselineskip26\p@
   \bib@device{\textwidth}{245.5\p@}%
  \endgroup
  \nobreak\@nobreaktrue
  \addvspace{19\p@}%
  \par
  \onecolumngrid@pop
 }%
}%
\def\bib@device#1#2{}%

\appdef\setup@hook{%
 \let\bibpreamble\@empty
 \bibsep\z@\relax
 \def\newblock{\ }%
}%
\appdef\setup@hook{%
 \def\bibfont{%
  \small
  \@clubpenalty\clubpenalty
 }%
}%
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
 \columnseprule \z@
 \columnsep 35\p@
 \c@secnumdepth-\maxdimen
 \onecolumngrid@push
 \section{\indexname}%
 \thispagestyle{plain}%
 \parindent\z@
 \parskip\z@ plus.3\p@\relax
 \let\item\@idxitem
 \onecolumngrid@pop
}{%
}%
\def\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@}%
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}%
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}%
\def\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ plus5\p@ minus3\p@\relax}%
\def\@journal@default{pra}%
\def\@pointsize@default{10}%
\def\rtx@apspra{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRA selected}%
}%
\def\rtx@apsprb{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRB selected}%
 \let\frontmatter@footnote@produce\frontmatter@footnote@produce@endnote
 \appdef\setup@hook{%
  \bibpunct{}{}{,}{s}{}{\textsuperscript{,}}%
  \let\onlinecite\rev@citealpnum
 }%
 \def\pre@bibdata{\jobname\bibdata@app}%
 \let\place@bibnumber\place@bibnumber@sup
}%
\def\rtx@apsprc{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRC selected}%
}%
\def\rtx@apsprd{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRD selected}%
}%
\def\rtx@apspre{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRE selected}%
}%
\def\rtx@apsprl{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRL selected}%
 \let\frontmatter@footnote@produce\frontmatter@footnote@produce@endnote
 \@booleanfalse\acknowledgments@sw
 \appdef\setup@hook{%
  \def\bibsection{%
   \par
   \begingroup
    \baselineskip26\p@
    \bib@device{\hsize}{72\p@}%
   \endgroup
   \nobreak\@nobreaktrue
   \addvspace{19\p@}%
  }%
 }%
\appdef\setup@hook{%
  \lengthcheck@sw{%
   \RequirePackage{times}%
  }{}%
}%
 \c@secnumdepth=-\maxdimen
 \appdef\setup@hook{%
  \@ifnum{\@pointsize=10\relax}{%
   \lengthcheck@sw{%
    \def\large{%
     \@setfontsize\large{12.5}{14\p@}%
    }%
    \def\normalsize{%
     \@setfontsize\normalsize{10.5}\@xiipt
     \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus6\p@ \@minus5\p@
     \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
     \abovedisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip
     \belowdisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip
     \let\@listi\@listI
    }%
    \def\small{%
     \@setfontsize\small{9.5}\@xipt
     \abovedisplayskip 5\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus4\p@
     \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
     \abovedisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip
     \belowdisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip
     \let\@listi\@listI
    }%
    \DeclareMathSizes{12.5}{12.5}{9}{6}%
    \DeclareMathSizes{10.5}{10.5}{7.5}{5}%
    \DeclareMathSizes{9.5}{9.5}{7.0}{5}%
   }{%
    \def\normalsize{%
     \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
     \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
     \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
     \abovedisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip
     \belowdisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip
     \let\@listi\@listI
    }%
   }%
  }{}%
 }%
 \textheight = 694.0\p@
}%
\def\rtx@apsprstper{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRST-PER selected}%
 \rtx@apsprb
 \@booleantrue\longbibliography@sw
}%
\def\rtx@apsprstab{%
 \class@info{APS journal PRSTAB selected}%
}%
\@booleantrue\footinbib@sw
\appdef\@bibdataout@rev{\@bibdataout@aps}%
\def\@bibdataout@aps{%
 \immediate\write\@bibdataout{%
  @CONTROL{%
   apsrev41Control%
   \longbibliography@sw{%
    ,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"%
   }{%
    ,author="08",editor="1",pages="0",title="",year="1"%
   }%
  }%
 }%
 \if@filesw
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{apsrev41Control}}%
 \fi
}%
\let\place@bibnumber\place@bibnumber@inl
\def\@bibstyle{apsrev\substyle@post}%
\appdef\setup@hook{%
 \@ifx{\place@bibnumber\place@bibnumber@sup}{%
  \footinbib@sw{}{%
   \class@warn{Citations are superscript numbers: footnotes must be endnotes; changing to that configuration}%
   \@booleantrue\footinbib@sw
  }%
 }{}%
}%

\def\substyle@post{4-1}%


\let\@bibitemShut\relax



\def\baselinestretch{2}% For double spacing


\endinput
```

Since I had no idea about the source of the error, probably the question has not been written well. Folks can reword it to be useful for future.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's known that `algorithm` is not compatible, as is, with `revtex4-1`; I believe that the authors of the AIAA class didn't even test it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any substitution to fix it?

Comment: Use another document class. If you are required to use AIAA, ask its maintainers.

Comment: Great. BTW, there is an answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231191/algorithm-in-revtex4-1

Comment: I tried it, by removing the loading of `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` in `AIAA.cls`. The result was as awful as it could be.

Comment: adding `\begin{document} \usepackage{algorithm} \usepackage{algpseudocode}`  to your MWE worked well for me with the aiaa.cls I have. Using the file you have attached here resulted with these errors. What version of aiaa.cls do you have ?

Comment: I also used `algorithm2e` with aiaa several times without fail