# The LaTex template offered by AIP cannot be inserted pseudocodes

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, pseudocode

In order to submit to Chaos, I downloaded **[the Latex Template](https://aip.scitation.org/cha/authors/jsprep)  AIP requests**.
But when I was going to insert the pseudo code like

```
\begin{algorithm}
    %\textsl{}\setstretch{1.8}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
    \caption{STVMD based on STFT}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \STATE Initialization:$\left\{ {s_{k,t}^1} \right\},\left\{ {\omega _{k,t}^1} \right\},\lambda _t^1,n \leftarrow 0$
        \STATE  ${s_{r,t}}\left( \omega  \right) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{s_r}\left( \tau  \right){w_h}\left( {t - \tau } \right)} \exp \left( {j\omega \tau } \right)d\tau $   (via STFT)
        \REPEAT
        \STATE $n \leftarrow n + 1$
        \STATE Update $ s_{k,t}^{n + 1} $ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_8})
        \STATE Update $\omega _{k,t}^{n + 1}$ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_9})
        \STATE Update $\lambda _t^{n + 1} $ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_10})
        \UNTIL $\sum\limits_{k=1}^P  {{{\left\| {s_{k,t}^{n + 1}\left( \omega  \right) - s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2} \mathord{\left/
                    {\vphantom {{\left\| {s_{k,t}^{n + 1}\left( \omega  \right) - s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2} {\left\| {s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2}}} \right.
                    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {\left\| {s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2}}}  < \varepsilon $  
        \STATE   Update ${s_k}\left( t \right)$ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_11_12})  (via ISTFT)
        \ENSURE  decomposed modes $ \left\{ {{s_k}\left( t \right)} \right\}$, $\left\{ {{\omega _k}\left( t \right)} \right\}$
    \end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm}
```

But the compilation throws out wierd erros:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\c@float@type
l.123 \end{algorithm}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\endcsname
l.123 \end{algorithm}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Extra \endcsname.
<recently read> \endcsname
l.123 \end{algorithm}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
(./aipsamp.bbl
```

which are in short **! Missing \endcsname inserted.**,**! Missing number, treated as zero.** and **! Missing number, treated as zero.**

I searched all over the Internet but got no solution to this error, anyone can help with the **pseudocode in the AIP LaTex template**？ Thanks a lot.

The complete document sample is

```
% ****** Start of file aipsamp.tex ******
%
%   This file is part of the AIP files in the AIP distribution for REVTeX 4.
%   Version 4.1 of REVTeX, October 2009
%
%   Copyright (c) 2009 American Institute of Physics.
%
%   See the AIP README file for restrictions and more information.
%
% TeX'ing this file requires that you have AMS-LaTeX 2.0 installed
% as well as the rest of the prerequisites for REVTeX 4.1
% 
% It also requires running BibTeX. The commands are as follows:
%
%  1)  latex  aipsamp
%  2)  bibtex aipsamp
%  3)  latex  aipsamp
%  4)  latex  aipsamp
%
% Use this file as a source of example code for your aip document.
% Use the file aiptemplate.tex as a template for your document.
\documentclass[%
 aip,
% jmp,
% bmf,
% sd,
% rsi,
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
% Conference Proceedings
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}


%% Apr 2021: AIP requests that the corresponding 
%% email to be moved after the affiliations
\makeatletter
\def\@email#1#2{%
 \endgroup
 \patchcmd{\titleblock@produce}
  {\frontmatter@RRAPformat}
  {\frontmatter@RRAPformat{\produce@RRAP{*#1\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}\frontmatter@RRAPformat}
  {}{}
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\preprint{AIP/123-QED}

\title[Sample title]{Sample Title:\\with Forced Linebreak}
% Force line breaks with \\
\author{A. Author}
 \altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}%Lines break automatically or can be forced with \\
\author{B. Author}%
 \email{Second.Author@institution.edu.}
\affiliation{ 
Authors' institution and/or address%\\This line break forced with \textbackslash\textbackslash
}%

\author{C. Author}
 \homepage{http://www.Second.institution.edu/~Charlie.Author.}
\affiliation{%
Second institution and/or address%\\This line break forced% with \\
}%

\date{\today}% It is always \today, today,
             %  but any date may be explicitly specified



\begin{algorithm}
    %\textsl{}\setstretch{1.8}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
    \caption{STVMD based on STFT}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \STATE Initialization:$\left\{ {s_{k,t}^1} \right\},\left\{ {\omega _{k,t}^1} \right\},\lambda _t^1,n \leftarrow 0$
        \STATE  ${s_{r,t}}\left( \omega  \right) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{s_r}\left( \tau  \right){w_h}\left( {t - \tau } \right)} \exp \left( {j\omega \tau } \right)d\tau $   (via STFT)
        \REPEAT
        \STATE $n \leftarrow n + 1$
        \STATE Update $ s_{k,t}^{n + 1} $ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_8})
        \STATE Update $\omega _{k,t}^{n + 1}$ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_9})
        \STATE Update $\lambda _t^{n + 1} $ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_10})
        \UNTIL $\sum\limits_{k=1}^P  {{{\left\| {s_{k,t}^{n + 1}\left( \omega  \right) - s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2} \mathord{\left/
                    {\vphantom {{\left\| {s_{k,t}^{n + 1}\left( \omega  \right) - s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2} {\left\| {s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2}}} \right.
                    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {\left\| {s_{k,t}^n\left( \omega  \right)} \right\|_2^2}}}  < \varepsilon $  
        \STATE   Update ${s_k}\left( t \right)$ based on Equation~(\ref{eqn_11_12})  (via ISTFT)
        \ENSURE  decomposed modes $ \left\{ {{s_k}\left( t \right)} \right\}$, $\left\{ {{\omega _k}\left( t \right)} \right\}$
    \end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm}




\bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aipsamp.tex ******
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231191/algorithm-in-revtex4-1/231265#231265), you may need to use [H] (capital H!) after \begin{algorithm}